# The word "but" in programming

Tags: language-agnostic, conditional-statements

This is very junior, but how does one express a "but" as a conditional statement? The language really doesn't matter. I was trying to wrap my brain around how it's interpreted in code and couldn't seem to find any information when researching.

for example in pseudo-code

```
 I like Apples, but I like Washington apples more
```

Comment: Can you give us a complete sentence using "but" for us to translate :)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. If you could give a concrete example that would really help.

Comment: "But" I'm not sure can be mathematically expressed accurately. If you can find a mathematical expression for something, it is easy to come up with a logic for it. But, ASAIK cannot always be expressed mathematically. Can you give us a context. I'm thinking - "I like Apples, but I like Mangoes more". Is this the kind of thing you have in mind?

Comment: I just corrected myself with Manish's example. That's more along the lines of what I was thinking.

Comment: In which case I would write `if Apples && !WashingtonApples` to express your sentiment - however, you don't say what you want to do with `but`

Comment: I'm having more trouble translating "I like Apples" than anything else. Maybe something like `apples = [Cox, Washington, Granny_Smith]; liking_for(apples) > 0 && liking_for(Washington) > liking_for(apples);`. As everyone is saying, the significance of "but" is that it contradicts an expectation that the reader might have: they think you're saying that apples are what you like, *but* then you're telling them you prefer a particular kind of apples. Computers don't guess so much in the first place, so they don't need their guesses corrected.

Comment: To me, that statement is about preferences. *In this context*, it's I prefer X, then Y, then Z. In code, you might think of it as `if (isWashingtonApple) { stuffMyself(); } else if (isApple) { eat(); } else { complainLoudly(); }`. But that's just my take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the literal translation of a `but` into a programming language might be hard, but (/chuckle) you can look at specific instances and find a way to translate them.

For example (using a previous poster's pees example)

```
I dislike peas but I'll sometimes eat them in salads
```

You can somewhat read this as

```
I don't eat peas but I'll eat them in salads
```

Given that interpretation, you can treat it as a special case and code it like

```
if(hasPeas()) {
    if(inSalad()) {
        willEat();
    } else {
        willNotEat();
    }
}
```

You can almost think of it like a guard or edge case condition. For example, when reading a file (using REALLY bad code to illustrate the idea):

```
text = "";
while(true) {
    while((count = canRead(fd)) <= 0) { // nothing to read
        if(count == EOF) { // EOF is a magic value meaning there will never be more to read
            return text;
        }
        wait(1000); // wait a bit to see if more text shows up to read
    }
    text += read(fd, count);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of any context in which "but" means something other than "and" (except for the fact that it implies a sense of contradiction, but I don't see how that would translate into code), so just use the language's "and"-operator, i.e. `&&` for most languages.

Comment: +1. This is clearly the correct answer. "but" means "and" in the same way that "any" means "one", but with a sense of contradiction (the difference between "not none" and "one", or "not without" and "with").

Answer (score 3):

"but" is declarative about a piece of knowledge, not imperative. You say "I dislike peas but I'll sometimes eat them in salads".

Programming in an imperative language like most are is done in terms of imperative commands. "Do X". "If X do Y". The closest thing to a "but" would be `else` or `else if`, ie:

```
if (value == 1)
{
   #do something
}
else
{
   #do something else
}
```

So if we were giving *imperative* instructions to our waiter, we might turn our declarative information about peas earlier ("I dislike peas but I'll sometimes eat them in salads") into a command "waiter, if entree has peas in salad, then serve entree, else if entree just has peas, then don't serve entree". In psuedocode, if our waiter (or compu-waiter) understood php5 this might read:

```
if (entree->hasPeasInSalad())
{
    serve(entree);
}
else if (entree->isPeas())
{
    discard(entree);
}
```

Comment: or maybe `if $entree->isPeas())` instead of `hasPeas`?

Comment: Perhaps because the php tag has been edited away, so the innocent reader does not expect lengthy elaborations about php5.

Comment: @Ingo I didn't notice that was removed. I've tried to remove some phpisms and just use psuedocode.

Comment: @Doug I think so, as you posted before the edit was done. Note that it was not me that downvoted you, I just wanted to let you know why someone else *might have* downvoted you.

Answer (score 1):

We have `unless` keyword in Ruby but I can't imagine using `but`.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly as an `else`?

"If x is less than 5 do this, but if x is greater than 5 do that."

```
if (x < 5) {
   doThis();
}
else {
   doThat();
}
```

Or maybe as an `and` with negation?

"If x is between 3 and 8 but not equal to 5, do this."

```
if (x >= 3 && x <= 8 && x != 5) {
   doThis();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sentance is purely declarative, and does not state something of the consequence of likeing apples or something else -- however I would expect that it would be something like;

```
var degreeOfLikeness = neutral;

if (object.type = Apple) {
    degreeOfLikeness = like_Degree_5;
    if (object.spicies = "Washington")
        degreeOfLikeness = like_Degree_8;
}

if (degreeOfLikeness > like_Degree_2) {
    object.eat();
    if (degreeOfLikeness > like_Degree_6) {
      output.say("Ummm!!!");
    }
}
```